# Turn Based Game broken

Tags: python, variables

I want to make a small turn based game. I've only coded so far as to do my turn and my turn only. However, when I perform my turn I don't do any damage to the cpu and I don't heal myself when the option is taken.

```
import random
print("Let's play a turn based game")
print("Your moves are:")
print("")
print("1) Fire Blast(18 to 25 HP) 2) Aura Sphere(10 to 35 HP) 3) Recover(Recover 10 to 30 HP)")
print("You can go first")
playerHP = 100
cpuHP = 100
fireBlast = random.randint(18,25)
auraSphere = random.randint(10,35)
recover = random.randint(10,30)

while playerHP >= 0 or cpuHP >= 0:
    print("")
    print("You have",playerHP,"HP")
    print("I have",cpuHP,"HP")
    playerMove = input("Which move do you choose?   ")
     print("Initiate player's move!")
        if playerMove == "Fire Blast" or "fire blast":
                         cpuHP == cpuHP - fireBlast
                         print("You used Fire Blast! I now have",cpuHP,"HP")
        elif playerMove == "Aura Sphere" or "aura sphere":
                         cpuHP == cpuHP - auraSphere
                         print("You used Aura Sphere! I now have",cpuHP,"HP")
        elif playerMove == "Recover" or "recover":
                         playerHP == playerHP + recover
                         print("Healed! You now have",playerHP,"HP")
        else:
            print("You didn't choose a move...")
```

Comment: What is you question? See [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to read what is a good question.
What is your Python version?
And quiclky you have indentation problems and '=' is not '=='

Answer (score 2):

The first problem lies in the if-line:

```
if playerMove == "Fire Blast" or "fire blast":
    #(...)
elif playerMove == "Aura Sphere" or "aura sphere":
    #(...)
elif playerMove == "Recover" or "recover": 
    #(...)
```

The lower-case values won't work. When this will be executed, first the `"Fire Blast" or "fire blast"` part will be evaluated, resulting in `"Fire Blast"` value, as boolean `or` of two non-empty strings is the first string. Instead you should use:

```
if playerMove == "Fire Blast" or playerMove ==  "fire blast":
    #(...)
elif playerMove == "Aura Sphere" or playerMove == "aura sphere":
    #(...)
elif playerMove == "Recover" or playerMove == "recover": 
    #(...)
```

or to simplify things you can use [`lower()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.lower):

```
playerMove = playerMove.lower()
if playerMove == "fire blast":
    #(...)
elif playerMove == "aura sphere":
    #(...)
elif playerMove == "recover": 
    #(...)
```

Second problem is the hp subtraction lines:

```
cpuHP == cpuHP - fireBlast
cpuHP == cpuHP - auraSphere
playerHP == playerHP + recover
```

THe `==` operator is used for comparing values. What you want is the asignment operator `=`:

```
cpuHP = cpuHP - fireBlast
cpuHP = cpuHP - auraSphere
playerHP = playerHP + recover
```

Comment: You may also write `cpuHP -= fireBlast` `cpuHp -=auraSphere` and `playerHP += recover`

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer

Comparisons in python (to test if values are equal) are `==`, assignments in python are `=`. You need to use `cpuHP = cpuHP - fireBlast` instead of `cpuHP == cpuHP - fireBlast`.

Your code, as pasted above, has some indentation errors in it.

You should be using two comparisons on either side of the `or` eg. `x == y or a == b`. A string always evaluates to true, so your first `if` will always run.

#### Tips (unsolicited advice)

You can use `.lower()` or `.upper()` to make your checks for strings easier. Eg:

```
x = input('stuff').lower()
```

or for better debugging:

```
x = input('stuff')
x = x.lower()
```

It can be really useful to wrap your program in a function, and break it down into smaller functions that help each other ("helper functions") because it allows you to do testing. Early on, the best way to do testing is using `assert`. Eg:

```
def execute_damage_move(dmg, hp):
    hp = hp - dmg
    return hp

fireBlastDmg = 20
cpuHP = 40

assert HP_after_damage_move(fireBlastDmg, cpuHP) == 20
# this statement tests to make sure the output of execute_damage_move is as expected

fireBlastDmg = 15
cpuHP = 75

assert HP_after_damage_move(fireBlastDmg, cpuHP) == 60
# this statement tests to make sure the output of execute_damage_move is as expected
```

Comment: Thanks, can't believe I overlooked that.